# Best way to share SikuliX scripts (and OS friendly)?

Tags: cross-platform, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-x

I have a Sikuli 2 script which is composed of:

- an *app.sikuli* directory
- with a *app.py* in it
- and several Things.png images

Most of this structure was auto generated by SikuliX while I was creating the script. If I have to switch to another method of creating a Sikuli project, please say so, it's new to me.

I want to "share" this script to any other OS (say I wrote it on Linux, and I want to share it with MacOSX, Windows...). And I want this script to be straightforward to execute (the less steps, the less complexity), but I can modify anything before sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the snippet from the Git Docs for Sikulix. Let me know if you found any other solutions because I only know of distributing the finished code for running the .exe on machines with the IDE or just Java installed (NOT TO EDIT -- UNLESS ANOTHER IDE IS BEING USED LIKE ECLIPSE WITH SELENIUM)

YT OF SELENIUM SIKULIX INTEGRATION https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k65uCl42hSg&list=PL2EKpjm0bX4LqPht11MRfu9R1qUOSAZn3

https://sikulix.github.io/docs/scripts/running-scripts

Where and how can a SikuliX script be stored#
When you need to distribute your SikuliX scripts you have two options: zip-file and jar-file, both variants pack the SikuliX script content in one file, which makes distribution easier. Both can run with SikuliX.

The jar-file variant has an option to be packed together with the scripting and SikuliX feature support (self contained), so it might be run on systems only having a valid Java installation.

variant zip-file#
It can be created in the SikuliX IDE with the file menu entry “Export packed source” and gets the ending .skl instead of .sikuli. As such it cannot be reopened for editing nor used for import, it can only be run using SikuliX features on systems having a valid SikuliX setup. In fact it is simply a zip-file, which can be brought back to a .sikuli folder using a zip utility. So be aware, that this variant does not really hide your script content.

variant jar-file#
It can be created in the SikuliX IDE (file menu entry “Export as jar”). It can be run using SikuliX features on systems having a valid SikuliX setup. The script source is contained in compiled form (Java byte code) and hence not visible, even if one accesses the jar content. So this variant gives some level of secrecy for your scripted workflow.

Comment: No Selenium here, just SikuliX alone.